# how to enter value in an array during runtime using ruby

Tags: ruby

how  to enter  the values in  an array  dynamically  and   to use it

and  I'm trying  to reverse it after getting the  input from the   keyboard.

Comment: Define a blank array `arr = []` and push the elements as `arr << 'abc'` and then to reverse use the Array#reverse method

Comment: There are multiple ways to add values to an `Array` in ruby. Please post the ode you tried so we can help on the specific problem.

Comment: ...or even just create an array from input. The easiest solution for your case would be `puts STDIN.each_line.to_a.reverse`.

Comment: I'm trying  to reverse  it  without  taking  the   help of  method  .. How  can I use it  ..

Comment: Well, there is no way to put an item into an array without the use of some method (`push`, `unshift`, `<<`...), so the problem is very imprecisely defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
array = []

puts "Please enter each item on a separate line, then"
puts "end the input by hitting ENTER on an empty line."

while line = gets.chomp
  break if line.empty?
  array << line
end

puts "You entered:"
puts array.reverse
```

You really need to read a basic tutorial about Ruby, I have recommended this one to a few people and they liked it: https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse-load an array (that is, load it in reverse order, so oldest is last) then use 'unshift' while you're adding the array elements.

```
array.unshift = gets.chomp
```